# SharePoint 2010: working with Excel files

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010

i am developing a SP2010 site on which i want to store some data files in xls format. here is the logic of how it works:
1) the user uploads file to specific data library.
2) the data from the file must be parsed and put into a list.

so here's the question: how can i parse an excel file inside an event receiver? are there any other tools besides excel services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option will be the **OpenXML** framework:

- [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en)
- [Reading Data from SpreadsheetML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/10/reading-data-from-spreadsheetml.aspx)

The only downside of this approach is that this framework only works with Office 2007/2010 documents.

If you have to use Office 2003 documents, you might want to have a look at **Office Automation**, which requires installing Office on the (SharePoint) Server:

- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)